# Check for any conditional compilation symbols in C#

Tags: c#, compilation, conditional-statements

Is it possible in C# to check for the existence of any conditional compilation symbol, not just one?

For example,

```
#if ANY_CONDITIONAL_COMPILATION_SYMBOL_IS_DEFINED
    MessageBox.Show( "Don't forget to remove the cc symbols before shipping.");
#else
    ...
```

Comment: Not all compilation symbols mean "this isn't a production build"... IMO you need to find which would be an issue, and handle those...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `||` operator:

```
#if (DEBUG || SOME_OTHER)
    MessageBox.Show(...)
#endif
```

More information about this preprocessor symbol could be obtained at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> You can use the operators == (equality), != (inequality) only to test
>   for true or false . True means the symbol is defined. The statement
>   `#if DEBUG` has the same meaning as `#if (DEBUG == true)`. You can use the operators && (and), || (or), and ! (not) to evaluate whether multiple
>   symbols have been defined. You can also group symbols and operators
>   with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest them:

```
#if DEBUG
#if FOOBAR
    MessageBox.Show( "Don't forget to remove the cc symbols before shipping.");
#endif
#endif
```

This would require both DEBUG and FOOBAR to be set for the message to show.

There isn't a way to check for *any* symbol, but you can just do that for all the symbols you use.

Comment: Indeed there is, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then you want to ensure that the final build shipped to client should be built without any conditional compilation arguments.

Conditional compilation arguments are specified as a switch to `csc` (the C# compiler). The build team can maintain a checklist (basically separate configuration) such that when solution is built, no conditional compilation arguments will be used for building the solution/project. There can be a separate configuration for build which is done for in house testing.

I do not think there is a way in C# to enumerate over conditional compilation arguments defined for the project as CC arguments are essentially used for compiling the project. They do not have any significance once the project gets built.